# how to wait user type finish in entry widget from tkinter only execute bind function

Tags: python, tkinter

I try search in stack overflow but I cant get the answer I need. Below is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=text)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

def show(*args):
    print(text.get())

text.trace_add("write", show)

root.mainloop()
```

I am looking for user to type finish in the entry widget and only auto trigger the show functions. Instead of this output:

[image]

i am looking for this output:

[image]

Please help.

Edit:
My show function contains below code:

[image]

Comment: Then it is better to bind on `<Return>` event (*Enter* key) on `entry` instead of `trace_add()`.

Comment: hi acw, that's what i did previously but now i don't want to press Enter.. hmm

Comment: can you put the code in a code block please? use 3 ~ symbols at the top and bottom of the code to create a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.after()` to execute `show()` in the callback of `trace_add()` as below:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=text)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

scheduler = None

def show():
    print(text.get())

def on_change(*args):
    global scheduler
    # cancel scheduler upon content change
    if scheduler:
        entry.after_cancel(scheduler)
    # create new scheduler to execute show one second later
    # change 1000 (ms) to whatever value you want
    scheduler = entry.after(1000, show)

text.trace_add('write', on_change)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of press enter, my expectation is delay the time to capture the text and execute the function, which is if user continue to key in 1 word and the time restart delay again until user stop typing.

Comment: @BrianTung Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` statement to only print 1234 when 1234 is inputted into the field.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=text)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

def show(*args):
  #If statement here
  if text.get() == "1234":
    print(text.get())

text.trace_add("write", show)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: hi princess, thanks for your advise but my show function have a lot complicated codes, it contain read excel and using the text.get() to find in the data frame and showing another column of values. i have edited my post

Comment: i am looking for the time delay but if i use root.after then the function only execute once.. if i use trace then when the user type in entry, the function start working and my GUI is lagging.. i looking for the time delay when the entry input is updated and execute the function